# Why can't I call a sub-function?

Tags: java

I can't get this Java code to work. I have read multiple examples, but none explains why the code doesn't work.

The code:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class UserInfo {

            public String Name = "Example Name";
            public int Age = 13;

            static int GetAge() {
                return (Age);
            }
        }

        UserInfo.GetAge();
    }
}
```

Please note I am very new to Java.

Comment: You're making a static reference to an instance method. Further, you can't even declare a static method in a non-static nested class.

Comment: Note that, while it *is* possible to put a class inside a method, that ability is barely used.

Comment: Oh and you should really follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names always start with lowercase.

Comment: @MCEmperor I have seen both. I have seen som libraries where everythin starts with "highcase" letters too. Are those libraries just a small couple of exceptions?

Comment: @MoltasC That must be in the case of the Java equivalent of constants: variables that are marked `static final`. Enum constants are implicitly static final, and thus are also written in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a non-static method from a static context. I have moved the class outside of the method and made it static.

Try the code below:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(UserInfo.GetAge());
    }

    static class UserInfo {
        public String Name = "Example Name";
        static int Age = 13;
        static int GetAge() {
            return (Age);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you want a dynamic class in where you can define the name and age, use this code below:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo("John", 13);
        System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s Age: %s", userInfo.getName(), userInfo.getAge()));
    }

    static class UserInfo {
        String name;
        int age;

        UserInfo(String name, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I have to ask, is correct that it outputs nothing? I want to get "Age" as the output.

Comment: Replace `UserInfo.GetAge();` with `System.out.println(UserInfo.GetAge());`

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should print it out now.

Comment: You want stuff printed, you gotta _say_ to print it; this is Java, not APL.

Comment: @Rab, I know but the point is to use a class and having a function in it and then call it.

Comment: @MoltasC In Java, the procedures you call "functions" are called *methods*. For instance, `getAge()` is a method.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call non-static method from static context without creating new UserInfo object. You need to create new UserInfo object

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class UserInfo {
            public String Name = "Example Name";
            public int Age = 13;

            int GetAge() {
                return (Age);
            }
        }
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
        userInfo.GetAge();

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and I was able to get userInfo age with this code

Answer (score 0):

Error 1:

`age` is an `instance` variable. You can not use it inside the `static` method `GetAge()`, so either make `Age` static or make a `getAge` instance...

```
   static int GetAge() {
        return (Age);
    }
```

Error 2: you can not access an instance variable `GetAge()` using a class name reference. To correct it, you have to create an object and use this reference to access it.

```
UserInfo.GetAge();  // Does not compile
```

Instead use:

```
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
userInfo.GetAge();
```

Generally, instance variables can not be used inside static methods and you can not use class reference to access an instance member in Java.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you cannot call a non-static method from a static context. You should need to move the inner class outside from the main method and make it static.

Try this one:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(UserInfo.GetAge());
    }

    static class UserInfo {

        public String Name = "Example Name";
        public static int Age = 13;

        static int GetAge() {

            return (Age);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exact duplicate of my answer that has been accepted.